# SceneKit SCNGeometryElement TriangleStrip vs triangles

Tags: scenekit

I have draw a scene which contains a SCNGeometryElement object. (it is a terrain. I have 2 triangles per grid item)
In order to optimize, i decided to remplace my triangle primitive by TriangleStrip.
But it does not give me the same result

My Vertex array is a succession of 4 points:

```
C  D
A  B
```

My indices array contains index of A, C, B and D
So when i work with TriangleStrip, scene kit is supposed to draw ACB and CBD triangles. That is what is said in apple documentation.

I am wondering what i should put in primitivecount. I tried several things. It changes the rendering but i can not retrieve the same result i had before with simple triangles...

Any idea ?

Thanks

```
let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: buffer_indices , primitiveType: .TriangleStrip, primitiveCount: Int(points_count), bytesPerIndex: sizeof(CInt))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a triangle strip the `primitiveCount` should be equal to `indexCount - 2`.

Alternatively you can use the Swift-friendly [`SCNGeometryElement(indices:primitiveType:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scngeometryelement/1523191-init) (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40900338/2997825)).

Comment: Where did you see in Apple official documentation indexCount -2 ? Thanks

Comment: it may not be in the documentation but works the same in OpenGL, Metal and other libraries. Take a piece of paper and draw a triangle strip with 3 indices, that makes 1 triangle. Then add 1 index, you have one additional triangle. Add `n` indices, you have `n` additional triangles. So the formula is easily verified.

Comment: Is indexCount number of vertices?

Comment: or number of indices?