# How to draw tens of thousands of lines in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, scenekit

I am going to draw a lot of lines in `SceneKit`. I searched how to draw lines and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21891749)

It works well for me, except it is not suitable for drawing a huge number of lines. When I am drawing tens of thousands of lines, the occupied RAM will be horrible (n Gb).

I am wondering if there is a way I can draw a large number of lines efficiently. All I need is 3D lines, whose from-to coordination and length may be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method described in your [referenceed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21891749) is correct, you just have not create `SCNGeometrySource/SCNGeometryElement/SCNNode` for each line, just fill the arrays:

```
SCNVector3 positions[] = {
    SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),    // line1 begin  [0]
    SCNVector3Make(10.0, 10.0, 10.0), // line1 end    [1]
    SCNVector3Make(5.0, 10.0, 10.0),  // line2 begin  [2]
    SCNVector3Make(10.0, 5.0, 10.0)   // line2 end    [3]
};

int indices[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
              // ^^^^  ^^^^
              // 1st   2nd
              // line  line
```

And then create geometry source from `NSData` with stride:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:positions length:sizeof(positions)];

SCNGeometrySource *vertexSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:data
                                            semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex
                                         vectorCount:POSITION_COUNT
                                     floatComponents:YES
                                 componentsPerVector:3 // x, y, z
                                   bytesPerComponent:sizeof(CGFloat) // size of x/y/z/ component of SCNVector3
                                          dataOffset:0 
                                          dataStride:sizeof(SCNVector3)*2]; // offset in buffer to the next line positions
```

If you have 10000 lines, then your positions buffer will be 2*3*10000*8 = **480KB**, and indices 2*10000*4 = **80KB**, which is really not much for GPU.

You can even further reduce buffers if you can reduce length of indices and/or positions. For example, if all your coordinates is integers in range -127..128 then passing `floatComponent:NO, bytesPerComponent:1` would reduce positions buffer to **60KB**).

Of course, this is applicible if all of your lines have same material properties. Otherwise, you have to group all lines with same properties in `SCNGeometrySource/SCNGeometryElement/SCNNode`.

Comment: As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037428/scenekit-scngeometryelement-trianglestrip-vs-triangles, you can skip the `NSData` conversion and use `SCNGeometryElement(indices:primitiveType:)` to generate your index buffer.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Just for someone else need to solve similar problems, drawing too many lines (like 300) in one geometry will crash your app. I do not know the reason, but it happens.